# Why is using a shared memorry and a sempaphore faster than using a pipe?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi

So I am using a raspberry pi and I created some programs in c++. I have created two that are sharing/sending pictures to each other by using pipes (function: pipe). And I have also created two that are sharing/sending pictures to each other by using shared memory and semaphores (functions: shmget, shmat, semget).

I have timed both of the above and discovered that using semaphores and shared memory is always 10 - 20 % faster. My question is why is this so? Can somebody explain to me what is happening around kernel that leads to this phenomenon?

Comment: pipe IPC method uses kernel side buffering - i.e. there are two data transfers which involve data copy: **user space->kernel space->user space** . Shared memory approach does not involve copy operations - the same physical memory pages are mapped into different virtual addresses of relevant processes. When first process modifies memory region it gets modified/mirrored in a second process just because it is the same memory block at physical level.

Answer (score 0):

Shared memory is like a drive-in cinema. The projector displays the movie on the screen and all those who have arrived in their cars and paid can see the movie as it plays. Or, in computer terms, one process writes the shared memory and any other processes that have it mapped can see it immediately.

A pipe is more like arriving at a market with a bunch of photos. The market-trader copies the photos one-at-a-time into his book, and if any customers arrive and want them, he copies them again into the customer's book. Or, in computer terms, the data is copied into a kernel buffer and thence once more to the user-land buffer of any client.